# D3 Change color and scale based on radio button

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am trying to figure out how to make my viz change upon a radio button.
I have this radio button:

```
<div>
        <input type="radio" name="dataset" value="sum_clients" checked> Clients 
        <input type="radio" name="dataset" value="sum_vendors"> Vendors

</div>
```

...

and the following script:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain ([0, 1, 2, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 1758668])
        .range (["white", "#cce0ff", "#b3d1ff", "#80b3ff", "#66a3ff", "#4d94ff", "#1a75ff", "#005ce6", "#003d99"]);


features.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(geodata,geodata.objects.collection).features) 
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d",path)
        .style("fill", function(d){return color(d.properties.sum_clients); })
        .style("stroke", "#837E7C")
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

What i am trying to achieve is to make the color part in style change from 
    color(d.properties.sum_clients)
to
    color(d.properties.sum_vendors)
when the radio button changes.

I also need the range of the color function to change (i have a totally different scale of colors for vendors)

I tried some on change functions to get the value of the radio button, but i never managed to make anything work.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what does your data look like? as in style("fill, function(d){ console.log(d); ?

Comment: The data comes from a topojson file. it returns an array that is pretty long, i cut it just to show the relevant data so its looks like this for one "node":

Comment: ` "properties": {
    "OBJECTID": 2616,
    "Join_Count": 1,
    "TARGET_FID": 158521,
    "STATEFP10": "36",
    "COUNTYFP10": "061",
    "TRACTCE10": "013100",
    "BLOCKCE10": "1005",
    "geoid10_1": 360610131001000,
    "latitude": 40.7621725,
    "longitude": -73.9848576,
    "sum_client": 1757567,
    "sum_vendors": 1105,
    "Shape_Leng": 0.00596142438176,
    "Shape_Area": 0.000001666195111
}, "arcs": [
    [9192, 9193, 9194, 9195] 
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make another color scale for vendors (I have a totally different scale of colors for vendors):

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain ([0, 1, 2, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 1758668])
        .range (["white", "#cce0ff", "#b3d1ff", "#80b3ff", "#66a3ff", "#4d94ff", "#1a75ff", "#005ce6", "#003d99"]);

var vendorcolor = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain ([0, 1, 2, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 1758668])
        .range (["white", "red", "green", "blue", "black", "yellow", "purple", "indigo", "violet"]);
```

Now in your style fill for path do it like this:

```
features.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(geodata,geodata.objects.collection).features) 
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d",path)
        .style("fill", function(d){
                   //get the value of the checked
                   var value = d3.select('input[name="dataset"]:checked').node().value;
                   if(value =="sum_vendors"){
                      return vendorcolor(d.properties.sum_vendors);
                   } else {
                      return color(d.properties.sum_clients); 
                   }
       })
        .style("stroke", "#837E7C")
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

Comment: Maybe better if we add `pathes = features.selectAll("path")`, and only call `pathes.style` after checkbox value changed.

Comment: yep @DavidGuan are correct. The code dealing with fill style has to also go in the radio change listener.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your replies. so trying to understand and apply it to my case, i ended up with the following:

Comment: `pathes = features.selectAll("path")
   d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() { 
    var value = d3.select('input[name="dataset"]:checked').node().value;
    pathes  .data(topojson.feature(geodata,geodata.objects.collection).features) //generate features from TopoJSON
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d",path)
     .style("fill", function(d){ 
         if(value =="sum_vendors"){
                      return vendorcolor(d.properties.sum_vendors);
                   } else {
                      return color(d.properties.sum_clients); 
                   }
     })`

Comment: This works pretty well, the only thing is that it does not display anything until i change the radio button (as the the on change function encloses everything). I have to find a way to have a default value that loads up with the page

Comment: On drawing you need to do the same process that you do on change of radio button. If my answer solves your problem kindly accept it as answer here is how you can do it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work